# Combining threading and numpy vectorize

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, scipy

do you know a neat routine which has the functionality of

```
def func_(a,b,c):
    "do some stuff"
    return (a+b*c)

func = np.vectorize(func_)

a_ = np.linspace(0,1,300)
b_ = np.linspace(-3,3,200)
c_ = np.linspace(10,20,55)
a,b,c = np.meshgrid(a_,b_,c_,indexing='ij')
X = func(a,b,c)
```

but uses multiple cores, i.e. multiple threads to calculate all the functions parallely? Thanks in advance!

Comment: With a function like `func_` you don't need `vectorize`.

Comment: Thats true. However, this is only an example.